# If I am comparing actual data vs. forecasted data, is the Durbin-Watson statistic useful?

Tags: time-series, independence, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

We are comparing our forecast vs actual data from the same time period and was using the mann-whitney test to help provide evidence our samples were not different. Someone challenged us saying the durbin-watson autocorrelation test shows the samples are not independent and thus the mann-whitney test can not be used.

Is this the purpose of the durbin-watson test? Meaning, can it be used to test if samples are independent?

Answer (score 0):

DW test tests only for the first order serial correlation in series. You could try to use it for the residual series defined as:

resids=actual - forecasted value

This would test if there is some linear structure left in the residuals, which could be used for augmenting your previous forecasts.

This test if often used for testing if your forecast is biased or not:

[Mincer-Zarnowitz regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77662/mincer-zarnowitz-regression)